# Yii CGridView add class or style for header cell

Tags: php, yii

I want to set some style or css class for header cell in specific column.

This changes css only for data cells in a column.

```
        'columns'=>array(
            array(
                'name'=>'id',
                'header'=>'#',
                'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width: 50px; text-align: center;', 'class'=>'zzz'),
            ),
```

How to set css or style in header cell of this column?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use [`headerHtmlOptions`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridColumn#headerHtmlOptions-detail).

```
'columns'=>array(
        array(
            'name'=>'id',
            'header'=>'#',
            'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width: 50px; text-align: center;', 'class'=>'zzz'),
            'headerHtmlOptions'=>array(...),
        ),
```

Comment: Thanks!!! I can't understand why Google didn't help me with my 'yii cgridview header htmloptions' like queries

Comment: You can access http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/ then find class you want and all public properties... you can see it... :D

Comment: And one more thing, if you need to set the class/style for filter ( for me it was for responsive features ) use `filterHtmlOption` the exact same way.

Answer (score 1):

filterHtmlOptions

If you want to style the content that the user enters in the filterbox - for
example "text-align : right" - then

```
'filterHtmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'text-align: right'),
```

is not going to work, because it will only style the outer table cell (td), and not the inner filter-container (div) or input element:

```
<td style="text-align: right;">
    <div class="filter-container">
        <input>
    </div>
</td>
```

What you can do is add a class to the outer table cell:

```
'filterHtmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'filterBoxRight'),
```

which will result in this:

```
<td class="filterBoxRight">
    <div class="filter-container">
        <input>
    </div>
</td>
```

Then run the following code:

```
$(document).on('ready', function(){
    $('.filterBoxRight').find('.filter-container').find(':input').css({
        'text-align': 'right',
    });
});
```